# Setting up 2D array in C++ with wchar_t?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, new-operator, wchar-t

I'm confused on setting up a 2D unallocated pointer to an array without using a `struct`.

This compiles in a 1D array:

`wchar_t *sServerArray = new wchar_t [128]();`

But this does not compile:

`wchar_t *sServerArray = new wchar_t [16][128]();`

I'm missing something simple I think! Can someone help?

A `struct` would be something like this:

```
struct sServerArray 
    {
    TCHAR *sName;
    };
sServerArray *sGN = new sServerArray [128]();
```

Then allocate the memory:

```
for (INT i = 0; i<16; i++)
    {
    sGN[i].sName = (TCHAR*)calloc(16,sizeof(TCHAR));
    }
```

I can do `auto`, but do I also need to allocate memory for each of the 16 rows?

Comment: C or C++ ? And how would you do this _with_ a struct?

Comment: Do like this: wchar_t *sServerArray = new wchar_t [16][128];

Comment: @sonulohani You probably meant `wchar_t (*sServerArray)[128] = new wchar_t[16][128]{};` ?

Comment: Yes youre right

Comment: @sonulohani, are there 16 rows, with each row allocated 128 characters, or is it 128 rows, with 16 characters in each row in your example?

Comment: @JeffR sonulohani's example isn't valid - but if the variable declaration had been ok you would have gotten 16 rows x 128 columns, `[16][128]`. It's usually easier to use a `std::vector<wchar_t> data(16*128);` and to decorate that with accessors for calculating rows & columns.